# Tree of grammar

Tags: algorithm, parsing, tree, grammar

I have a lab in the university. But I don't understand how I can do it.
I have a grammar of some language(for example, arithmetic expressions grammar). I must build tree of this grammar(I don't know how). Then I must determine, whether input sentence is sentence of this language? How can I do it?
P.S. I've read few chapters of Dragon Book, but I havn't found anything I need.
P.P.S. I can't use lex/flex and yacc/bison.

---

**EDIT** Sorry! I shuild be more attentive. Really I have a grammar and I must build tree using this grammar and input sentence(I understand how to do it) if it possible(in another case I must show message about it). Is there any simple for understanding algorithms for it? I can use grammar of any simple language like arithmetical expressions.

Comment: I'm puzzled by how one would build a *tree* node out of a recursive rule like `<syntax> ::= <rule> | <rule> <syntax>`, unless one used identifiers to indicate the recursion.  Can you find any examples in your textbook?

Comment: Okay, with that edit you want to use Kendrick's answer. What part are you having trouble with? (Going in order of what he says, ignoring what you say you know and don't know already.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is theoretical since it's homework, and not something you actually need to code at this point. (Kendrick's answer covers the code approach)

The basic idea is to start with your BNF start variable and try to figure out how to expand it, applying rules one at a time, to see if you can come up with your input sequence.

For a ruleset like the following:

```
(1) start: expression

(2) expression: expression '+' term
(3)           | expression '-' term
(4)           | term

(5) term: 'a'
(6)     | 'b'
```

Given the expression `a + b - a`, you would go something like this:

a. `start` (given)
b. `expression` (1)
c. `expression '-' term` (3)
d. `expression '-' 'a'` (5)
e. `expression '+' term '-' 'a'` (2)
f. `term '+' term '-' 'a'` (4)
g. `'a' '+' term '-' 'a'` (5)
h. `'a' '+' 'b' '-' 'a'` (6)

So that's how you do it one step at a time... Now the trick is, you need to trace out all your rule invocations. So your real tree would look something like this:

```
                          start
                            | (b)
                        expression
                        /   |   \ (c)
               expression  '-'  term
                /  |  \ (e)       | (d)
       expression '+' term       'a'
           | (f)        | (h)
          term         'b'
           | (g)
          'a'
```

It's a little complicated at first, but once you actually see how it's done it's not too hard to pick up.

**Note:** Some people find it easier to work backwards, starting with your input and then applying rules in reverse to try to find your start expression. When you write a parser, you will inevitably need to follow this route on some level.

**EDIT:** I listed all the expression steps using lowercase letters above, and then showed that each set of branches from the tree actually corresponds with one of the rule applications. May or may not help.

Comment: I would imagine that this answer will not help them. They could find this and more in the book so it would seem they want you to give them working code.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Maybe not, but (a) I haven't read the Dragon Book, and (b) the poster has yet to give sufficient detail as to what exactly s/he needs (and has already tried). So this is a good stab in the right direction.

Comment: I think the OP is also unclear about how "applying [the] rules" is actually done. There is also the curious stipulation that the *grammar* needs to be implemented as a tree (though that almost sounds like a misunderstanding of the lab instructions). But as you say - not enough information.

Comment: @Lars: True enough. I think that's part of the problem-- maybe it's not clear that you can't form a tree of a grammar, just a parse tree for a particular input using the grammar's rules. In any event, I made an edit to show the rule applications in action as the tree is formed.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I've done this, so I'm going to give you the short theoretical answer.  I'm sure someone else will have a more in-depth explaination.

Since you haven't said what you've done (and you should as part of your questions in the future), the first step is to tokenize the input.

Once you have the tokens, you can build a state machine to walk the tokens and push them into the desired tree structure.  This should be covered in your book (I haven't read it) but you probably want to start by building a model on paper (or electronic) and consider valid inputs from each step.  What's a valid left hand value for an equality statement?  If you have token x on the tree, where can you go from here?

If you can't determine from the current state where to go next, then you may need to implement look-ahead in your state machine (whether this is required depends on the complexity of your language).

Again, I haven't done this in over 10 years, so my recollection is fuzzy.  Hopefully I've given enough of a framework for you to refine your answer or give others who are more knowledgeable on the subject to roast me for being wrong or out of date (and thus arriving at the answer you're looking for as a group).

Comment: No-no-no. I must build exactly tree of grammar, i.e. I have a grammar description in BNF notation(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) and I must build tree of this grammar. Grammar can be fixed.

Comment: +1 for good high-level technical overview. Not sure if your approach or mine is what the original poster is going for here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer this, but there isn't really enough material to work with - I am left with these questions:

- As this is a university lab, isn't there accompanying study material or classes? Also, how much time to do you have?
- What have you tried so far?
- Can you hard-code a given grammar into your program, or does your program need to be able to read any grammar from a file and build a parse-tree from that?
- How complex are the grammars; specifically: are they recursive?
- Are the grammar tokens single-character or multi-character?

Edit: Taking the comment and the updated question into account: I think the most straight-forward approach would be a recursive descent parser, which builds the tree as the input is matched. Look for Niklaus Wirth's "Compiler Construction" book, which has been made available as PDF on the web, and which describes a RDP for a simple language.

The basic idea of a recursive descent parser is that every rule in the grammar corresponds to a function, and each function checks the next token and calls the corresponding next-lower parse function. For example, if your grammar has a rule

`expression : constant '+' constant`

the associated parsing method would look like this:

```
void parseExpression() {
    parseConstant();
    Token token = peek_at_next_token();
    if (token == '+') {
        parseConstant();
        ... tree building code here ...
    }
    else
        throw ParseException("Expected '+', found "+token);
}
```

But see also the other answers to this question.

Comment: 1. Oh, I from Belarus and there is very bad educatinal system. 2. I've only read Dragon Book. 3. Yes, I can. 4. Complexity same as in arithmetic expressions grammar 5. Multi-character.